# Visualising entity density on a 2D plane using pcolormesh in matplotlib, Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science, heatmap

I am trying to recreate the following heatmap (created with R) with Python.

[image: Entity density in a room. The lighter colors equate denser entity.]

This heatmap represents the entity concentration in a room, where the lighter color equate denser entity. The X axis is length in meters and the Y axis is height in meters.

Currently, I have been trying to recreate the data with matplotlib's pcolormesh. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to understand how to define X and Y columns for the heatmap.

The following code produces the heatmap below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0, 0, 1,  1, 2, 2],
               "y": [3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4],
               "concentration": [1123, 1238, 1285, 1394, 5123, 8712]})

plt.pcolormesh(df)
plt.show()
```

[image: Produced heatmap by code.]

Whereas I would like to see something like this:
[image: Expected result.]

As you can see, for X and Y I actually use values from columns in the dataframe.
Basically, X and Y are coordinates and the color at those pixels is dependent on the value of concentration (third column).

I tried to pass the arguments like that:

```
plt.pcolormesh([df["x"], df["z"]], df["concentration"])
plt.show()
```

But this leads to the following error:
TypeError: pcolormesh() takes 1 or 3 positional arguments but 2 were given

How am I to represenet the concentration data as a 2D array?
Am I even on the correct path?

Comment: Unfortunately, both scatter and contourf functions produce empty plots, while imshow raises:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'. Did you mean: 'shape'?

Comment: `plt.imshow(df["concentration"].values.reshape(3,2), extent=[0,2,3,4])`?  `plt.scatter(df["x"], df["y"], c=df["concentration"], marker='s', s=500)` with parameters depending on your data. `plt.tricontourf(df["x"], df["y"], df["concentration"])`

Comment: With seaborn: `sns.heatmap(df.pivot('y', 'x', 'concentration'), annot=True)`

Comment: Thank you, tricontourf and the seaborn heatmap provided the best looking graphs.